# How can i split particular data(status,name) from this variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

1. [**This is the output of pm2 describe in node js. I want status = online,name = abc,restarts = 0....**
          var Status = " Describing process with id 12 - name abc

   ┌───────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
                            │ status            │ online                                 │                   │ name              │ abc                                   │                   │ restarts          │ 0                                     │                   │
   uptime            │ 2D                                 
   │                     | script path       │ *.js            │
                  │ script args       │ N/A                                              │
                  │ error log path    │ *log │
                  │ out log path      │ *.log   │
                  │ pid path          │ /*pid       │
                  │ interpreter       │ node                                             │
                  │ interpreter args  │ N/A                                              │
                  │ script id         │ 12                                               │
                  │ exec cwd          │ *                               │
                  │ exec mode         │ fork_mode                                        │
                  │ node.js version   │ 6.9.5                                            │
                  │ watch & reload    │ ✘

   - List item

     │
                 │ unstable restarts │ 0                                                │
                 │ created at        │ 2017-03-22T10:37:04.715Z                         │
                 └───────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
                  Code metrics value 
                 ┌────────────┬────────┐
                 │ Loop delay │ 0.54ms │
                 └────────────┴────────┘
                  
                  Use `pm2 logs ristserver \[--lines 1000\]` to display logs
                  Use `pm2 monit` to monitor CPU and Memory usage 
                 "][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxHGG.jpg)

Comment: Can't read this. Maybe a screenshot will be more helpful?

Comment: var statusodsss = " Describing process with id 12 - 
            ┌───────────────────┬────────────────────────                                          
 │ status            │ online                                           │
            │ name              │ *                                       │
            │ restarts           │ 0                                       │
            │ 
             └───────────────────┴────────────────────────  "

Comment: Inside string i have data like this with in square box. this is check service status for node js server using pm2.